Microsoft Outlook Add-in - Microsoft 365
I'm experimenting with an Outlook Add-in to install it on both Outlook Web and the Outlook Desktop Application. When I run the sample code using npm run start, Outlook redirects to the sign-in page. Here, we are required to sign in with a Microsoft 365 account, and personal accounts are not permitted. After signing in with a Microsoft 365 account, it stores the details in the .fx folder and saves the data in homeId.cache.appStudio and token.cache.appStudio.json. Subsequently, it uses these details to spawn the Outlook Add-in. This process is repeated every time we run the server.
This command is in preview.
Using account: sample@outlook.com
TitleId:
AppID:

I have two questions:

Once everything is set up, I am able to install the Outlook plugin in my personal Outlook account as well. So why does it require a Microsoft 365 account?

Also, why do we receive a log This command is in preview


note: Office Add-in Task Pane project using Yo Office

The Yo Office generator is configured for a seamless debugging experience. The reason you have to sign in with a business account is because it's authenticating with your account to install the manifest.
If you check your debug configurations in VSCode you should see a lot of them. You can launch the solution with Outlook desktop or other ways.

Also, why do we receive a log This command is in preview

The command that does the automatic sideloading is in preview I guess.
